# How to pass dict value into class as argument

Tags: python, selenium, pageobjects

I have below page object want to simplify it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from support.utlis import DriverUtil

class LoginPage:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = DriverUtil.get_driver()

    def username_input_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="txtUsername"]')

    def password_input_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="txtPassword"]')

    def login_button(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[value="Login"]')
```

I want to have a single elementMap dict variable which can pass into class. Is that possible? Like below code.
I tried pass it as self.elements_map = elementsMap. Not working.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from support.utlis import DriverUtil

elementsMap = {
    'usernameInputField': 'input[name="txtUsername"]',
    'passwordInputField': 'input[name="txtPassword"]',
    'login_button': 'input[value="Login"]'
}

class LoginPage:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = DriverUtil.get_driver()
        self.elements_map = elementsMap

    def username_input_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.elements_map[usernameInputField])

    def password_input_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.elements_map[passwordInputField])

    def login_button(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.elements_map[login_button])
```

I cannot find a way to pass the dict key/value pair into class. Need some help. Thanks!

Comment: In def __init__(), have you tried adding elementsMap as an input into the function (e.g. def __init__(self, em)) and then when you call the class inputting elementsMap as em?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the dict key as a string in your field getter functions:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from support.utlis import DriverUtil

elementsMap = {
    'usernameInputField': 'input[name="txtUsername"]',
    'passwordInputField': 'input[name="txtPassword"]',
    'login_button': 'input[value="Login"]'
}

class LoginPage:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = DriverUtil.get_driver()
        self.elements_map = elementsMap

    def username_input_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.elements_map['usernameInputField'])

    def password_input_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.elements_map['passwordInputField'])

    def login_button(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.elements_map['login_button'])
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite follow..